# Google Spreadsheet/EXCEL] How do I get the last value in a Row? Using A1 as the first cell?

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets

```
  A       B        C         E         F
```

1 Bob      ------Chris-------Taylor---------Joe

2 Cake -----Fruit -------Chocolate---Eggs

3

4

5

How do I go about using a formula that will always choose the last cell in row A1:F1?

How do I get the value of the cell on row 2 that is the last cell with data? (in my case, Joe)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The value in the last used cell in row #**2** is:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(2:2<>""),2:2)`

The value in the last used cell in row #**1** is:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(1:1<>""),1:1)`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have text values in A1:F1 as per your example you can get the last one with this formula

`=LOOKUP("zzz",A1:F1)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way (assuming there is no blank cell inside the data)

```
=INDEX(A1:F1,1,COLUMNS(A1:F1)-COUNTBLANK(A1:F1))
```

[image]